# Give the new basis $(H_k)_{k=0,1,2,3}$ Of $R_3[X]$ to express $P$ by $P(0),P(1),P'(0),P'(1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, change-of-basis

Hello MathstackExchange..

Let $P\in \mathbb{R}_3[X]$ be represented in its canonical form: $P=\sum_{k=0}^3a_kX^k$.
Express $P$ by $P(0),P(1),P'(0),P'(1)$.

What's given as a hint is:
Give the new basis $(H_k)_{k=0,1,2,3}$ (where $(H_k)$ represents the Hermite Polynomial) Of $\mathbb{R}_3[X]$, that permits that expression and  verifies:

for $k=0$:
$H_0(0)=1,H_0(1)=0,H'_0(0)=0,H'_0(1)=0$

for $k=1$:
$H_1(0)=0,H_1(1)=1,H'_1(0)=0,H'_2(1)=0$

for $k=2$:
$H_2(0)=0,H_2(1)=0,H'_2(0)=1,H'_3(1)=0$

for $k=3$:
$H_3(0)=0,H_3(1)=0,H'_3(0)=0,H'_4(1)=1$

My problem is I really don't understand what I'm supposed to do.. How am I supposed to get the desired basis with what I'm given? and how to connect it to the expression of $P$? Any hints would be really appreciated.

I get that $P(0)=a_0, P(1)=a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3, P'(0)=a_1, P'(1)=a_1+2a_2+3a_3$

Am I supposed to express the coefficients $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$ in terms of $P(0),P(1),P'(0),P'(1)$?

I won't lie this is a homework that i'm not really able to solve.

Sorry if anything was lost with the translation of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you solve for the $a_i$ in terms of $P(0), P(1),P'(0), P(1)$, substitute these values into the expression for $P$, and collect like terms, you'll have solved the problem.

Comment: But then the $H_k$ polynomials wouldn't play any role..

Comment: When you collect the terms with coefficient $P(0)$, the polynomial that $P(0)$ multiplies is $H_0$. Ditto for the other values and polynomials.

Comment: Aha, so the factor that is multiplied by $P(0)$ is $H_0$, thank you for your help.

Comment: What about $H_3$ for example though?.

Comment: It's the polynomial multiplying $P'(1)$ and turns out to be $X^2(X-1)$. Personally, I find it easier to construct the [Hermite interpolant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation#Usage) directly.

Comment: Aha, so it's really simple, just dumped by a bunch of unnecessary wording /:, thank you very much for your help.